# Titanium ACS SDK - 404 Failed to Authenticate User

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I am trying to access the Appcelerator Titanium SDK for ACS after authenticating a user through Social Integrations. I am using the following code, which is copied line for line from the [ACS Kitchen Sink example application](https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.cloud/tree/master/commonjs/example), and I still cannot get it to work. The call to log the user in is successful, but the subsequent call to PhotoCollections API returns "404 - Failed to Authenticate user".

I am using oauth 3 legged authentication with the User Authentication Scheme set to Authorization Server. I have also tried other ACS APIs, without any luck. Please help! I've been stuck on this for 2 weeks now.

```
fb.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
if (e.success) {

    Cloud.SocialIntegrations.externalAccountLogin({
        type : 'facebook',
        token : fb.accessToken

    }, function(e) {
        if (e.success) {
            var user = e.users[0];
            Cloud.PhotoCollections.create({
                name : 'Party Pictures'
            }, function(e) {
                if (e.success) {
                    var collection = e.collections[0];
                    alert('Success:\n' + 'id: ' + collection.id + '\n' + 'name: ' + collection.name + '\n' + 'count: ' + collection.counts.total_photos + '\n' + 'updated_at: ' + collection.updated_at);
                } else {
                    alert('Error:\n' + ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
                }
            });

        } else {
            alert('Error: ' + ((e.error && e.message) || JSON.stringify(e)));
        }
    });

}
```

});

Comment: I'm having the same issue, however with KeyValue pairs. I'll also be integrating photo collections and I have a feeling it's all related. So if someone could help, please do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that multiple posts online were wrong about the server configuration needed to do this. Make sure that your "User Authentication Scheme" is set to "API Server" and **not** "Authorization Server". It turned out to be that simple for me.